# dynamic visualization of spatiotemporal data on a grid

Tags: r, kml, google-earth, spatio-temporal-data

I am handling spatiotemporal data and it is a quite new area for me.

Basically I have data related to the position of cars at a given time in Montreal. I would like to dynamically visualize the density of cars in a grid.

I am using R with some appropriate libraries such as plotKML, spacetime, sp, ..., which are useful to link R with Google Earth. I have already manually computed the density of cars and the data looks like that:

```
                   Time   Latitude   Longitude Dens
793 2016-02-23 23:20:56 45.4963903 -73.5596835 257
183 2016-02-23 04:48:38 45.5471917 -73.5492618 57
141 2016-02-23 04:39:58 45.5471535 -73.5491820 157
258 2016-02-23 05:04:08 45.5357973 -73.5593413 13
846 2016-02-23 23:31:56 45.5031632 -73.5791742 420
236 2016-02-23 04:59:33 45.5471562 -73.5492615 269
128 2016-02-23 04:37:18 45.5470988 -73.5492218 11
886 2016-02-23 23:40:11 45.5106078 -73.5786010 50
524 2016-02-23 22:25:34 45.4961470 -73.5591993 189
741 2016-02-23 23:10:21 45.4961615 -73.5591900 57
```

Now I should concretely visualize it in some way. I was thinking to use a grid, and plotting bubbles for each cell, with radius proportional to the density, or nothing if in that cell at that given time the density is 0.

I think most of the work can be done by properly using the plotKML function, since in some case it is possible to "intelligently" display bubbles (as shown in the wiki tutorial of plotKML [here](http://gsif.isric.org/doku.php?id=wiki:tutorial_plotkml)). For example, if we get rid of the Time variable, one (static) solution is the following:

```
library(sp)
library(plotKML)
library(spacetime)

# from raw data in df to "clean" data
mydf = createmydf(df)

spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
  coords = mydf[,c("Longitude","Latitude")],
  data = data.frame(mydf[,"Dens"]),
  proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# static plot:
plotKML(spdf, LabelScale = .1, colour_scale=rep("red", 2))
```

And the output for this is this (static) picture:

[image]

Now the question is: is it possible to do the same but in a dynamic way (i.e. considering the temporal dimension)?.

I tried to use the STFDF function. For this I computed a full space-time grid with n spatial locations and m times. This represents the input of STFDF, together with n x m observations (Densities in my case). This is the code:

```
# gridSpace: n x 2 matrix with Latitude and Longitude positions
# gridTime: a sequence of times, a vector of length m
# Dens: vector of length n x m
sp <- SpatialPoints(gridSpace[c("Longitude","Latitude")])
proj4string(sp) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
mydf.st = STFDF(sp, gridTime, data.frame(Dens))

plotKML(mydf.st)
```

In this case the plot is fine but there are just points of fixed dimension and changing the color with the time. Does somebody know a way to change this representation with bubbles of dynamic radius or bars? I think it should be related to the plotKML function. Or should I switch to another time function such as STIDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution with the raster package combined together with the input of the STFDF function which are n spatial locations, m times and n x m observations. This input is computed by the function `mySTGrid` and then used for the "rasterplot", properly performed in the `RasterPlot` function:

```
library(raster)

# 51, 101, 101 grid dimensions - 1 (time + 2D)
# in this case 50 time intervals and 100 x 100 spatial cells
newG = mySTGrid(mydf,51,101,101)

gridSpace = newG$SGrid
gridTime = newG$TGrid
Dens = newG$Dens

RasterPlot(gridSpace,gridTime,Dens)
```

where `RasterPlot` is defined like that:

```
RasterPlot <- function(gridSpace,gridTime,x)
{
  dfras = DfSplittedOverTime(gridTime,gridSpace,Dens)

  spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
    coords = dfras[c("Longitude","Latitude")],
    data = dfras,
    proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))


  gridded(dfras) = ~Longitude+Latitude
  proj4string(dfras) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

  delta = as.numeric(gridTime[2] - gridTime[1])*3600/2
  time.begin = as.POSIXct(unclass(as.POSIXct(gridTime))-delta, origin="1970-01-01") 
  time.end = as.POSIXct(unclass(as.POSIXct(gridTime))+delta, origin="1970-01-01") 

  dfras_LL = brick(dfras)
  dfras.ts <- new("RasterBrickTimeSeries", rasters = dfras_LL, sampled = spdf,
                  TimeSpan.begin = time.begin, TimeSpan.end = time.end)
  setwd(kmldir)
  plotKML(dfras.ts, colour_scale=SAGA_pal[[1]])
  setwd(mydir)
}
```

Basically the idea is to rearrange the dataset considering every time variable as a new variable (i.e. column) together with the spatial coordinates. So the first two columns are latitude and longitude, and then starting from the third column we have the data of interest (densities in this case) rearranged by time (the dataset is a n x (m+2) matrix). This is done in the `DfSplittedOverTime` function:

```
# starting from the input of STFDF builds the dataset
# structuring the data by latitude, longitude, times (coloumns)

DfSplittedOverTime <- function(timePoints,spacePoints,data)
{
  m = length(timePoints)
  n = nrow(spacePoints)
  out = spacePoints

  idx = seq(0,m*n,n)
  for(i in 1:(length(idx)-1)){
    out = cbind(out,data[(idx[i]+1):(idx[i+1])])
  }

  colnames(out)[3:ncol(out)] = as.character(timePoints)
  out = data.frame(out)

  return(out)
}
```

In this case the output is something like that (here I have zoomed in Google Earth the part related to Montreal at a given time, notice that it is a screenshot since you can play with the time bar on the top left and the color of each cell is actually changing):

[image]